# Material for character silhouette

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

I wanna make a animation made out of silhouettes (as a solid shape of a single color) like

[image]

[this](http://prntscr.com/idmpsx),

or

[image]

[this](http://prntscr.com/idmsb8)

or even like

[image]

[this](http://prntscr.com/idmtan).

Some people say to not put any material at all, but then that would be a problem if I want to have colored character.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: please edit your question so that we can see the pictures without selecting"this". I suppose you have a picture icon on the editor of stack exchange.

Comment: And, I am not quite sure what your question is. Is your question, "I would like to show objects in silhouette. I found out that having no material gets black silhouette but how can I make silhouette in other colours?" ?

Comment: Oh, and just one more thing. What render setting do you use? blender internal or cycles?

Comment: @RaebelChristo please put a bit more effort on describing what you want,and use the tools provided by this site to add images directly into the question.

Comment: Can you not just use the background shader on meshes?

Comment: Looks like an Emission material with *only* Camera visibility would do the trick. Set the color of emission to set the color of the silhouette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **Blender render** then check the ***Shadeless*** option in the **Material** tab:-

[image]

And if you are in **Cycles** then use this node setup to create a Shadeless material:-

[image]

Comment: Another question now I have is, how would I make this silhouette character cast shadows, not on itself, but on the surrounding objects? If not possible just drop it.

Comment: Just plug in the "is diffuse ray" instead of "is camera ray", that way the object will behave as if has a diffuse surface.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it might be possible with absence of light and texture.
I also think that that might be just shadow animation or maybe even combined decals. To get that effect in 3D, I think you might need to turn off shading all together. You can somehow [turn off the lighting apparently.](https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22060)
But I also think that most of it is made using actual shadow puppets.

**Example:**

[image: How that technique looks apparently]
The source is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180526185722/http://www.creativefluff.com:80/films/animation/babes-lair-walt-vervain-stunning-beautiful-shadow-animation/)

I am unsure if that answer in the Blender forum will help you, if it doesn't, you can use something like a 3D Engine without shading and shadows by default like Three.js or make a 2D animation.
My opinion of the techniques used in the pictures you have given me that all are 2D sprites or no lighting. Actually, the Tintin one looks like it is 3D no lighting with a green screen applied to a 2D image.

**EDIT:** Yes! I found a tutorial to do just that, it turns out if you put a really dark texture, it will look like a sillhouette(I thought it would give a little shine). [The tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PeTbIfUe3A) is here even though it is kind of outdated, it still is basically the same thing.